# Custom URL using resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have routes that I would like to include a board's id followed by it's slug:

```
/boards/1234/example-board
```

I can achieve this by writing the following:

```
get '/boards/:id/:slug', to: 'boards#show'
```

but will only apply to whatever action I assign to it and will not apply to nested routes. Currently the routes for boards are as so:

```
resources :boards, only: [:index, :show]
```

How can I use my custom url and have it apply towards all of my board actions and any nested routes?

Answer (score 0):

**May I ask why you need the `id` AND `slug`?**

You could easily do `resources :boards, only: [:index, :show], param: :slug`

and then do `Board.find_by_slug(params[:slug])`

**If you must have both you could try:**

It won't be the exact same order in your URL but you could use a [scope](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers)

```
scope ':slug' do
   resources :boards, only: [:index, :show]
end
```

Comment: There's no way to get them in the order I described?

Comment: Not to my knowledge